# How to increase disk space?

Tags: disk-usage, cleanup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space)

I am running out of space on my notebook, so I thought I would delete some unused stuff.

I was thinking about:

- cleaning the home folder as explained in: [Cleaning up my Home Directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14503/cleaning-up-my-home-directory)
- removing old logs from /var/log
- removing apt cache

Any other ideas?

Comment: You may also find useful information here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17467

Answer (score 11):

Remove old kernel packages (leave the latest one or two). I'd suggest something like Synaptic for this and you want to search the Installed section for `linux-image` and `linux-headers`.

The `linux-image` and `linux-headers` for each kernel version combines to about 200MB of disk space. On an old system that has gone through a lot of updates, this can easily give you back a few gigabytes of space.

Comment: This has also a nice side-effect of having a smaller boot menu. I smiled when I saw two screens of kernels (at the GRUB boot menu) at a friend :p

Answer (score 5):

A `sudo apt-get clean` will remove cached .debs that are sitting on disk from updates.

Answer (score 3):

I usually remove

- apps I don't use
- usused fonts, themes and icons

Answer (score 3):

You could also identify files that you don't often use and compress them. In particular, plain text files that are GZipped can still be read via the terminal with `less`.